# pasar una variable de Ajax a PHP

Tags: php, ajax, base-de-datos, variables

espero que esten bien, tengo un problema y necesito ayuda para poder guardar un url en base de datos o mandarla por correo, espero puedan ayudarme

ese es el codigo html y el ajax... en el codigo indico la variable que guardar en php para mandar enla base de datos ( es la url que se genera para la imagen que seria --> VAR image) no se sia posible o como funcionaria...

Nombre:

```
<label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
<input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto"><br>

<label class="form-label semibold" for="tick_descrip">Descripción</label>
    <div class="summernote-theme-1">
        <textarea id="summernote" name="summernote" class="summernote" name="name"></textarea>
    </div>
                                    
                            
<div class="btn_form">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar"  class="btn_submit" value="Enviar">
    </div>
```

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: 200,
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function(image) {
                console.log("Image detect...");
                uploadImage(image[0]);
                console.log(image[0]);
            }
        }
    });
});

  

function uploadImage(image) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", image);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        success: function(url) {
            console.log(url);     
            var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'https://pruebaoedher.000webhostapp.com/' + url); <------ esta es la VAR que quiero guardar en base de datos)
        
            $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", image[0]);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
        

    });
 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola qué tal, por lo que entiendo ese `var image` es lo que deseas que se guarde en la BD, para ello tienes que mandar todo esto: `var image = $('<img>').attr('src', 'https://pruebaoedher.000webhostapp.com/' + url); ` por el parámetro `data` del AJAX y podría ser que lo reciba un controlador que ejecute el proceso de guardar esa variable en la base de datos.

Comment: que variables quieres pasar de ajax a php???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 justamente Var Image la quiero guardar en una variable php para posteriormente mandarla por correo o guardarla en BD.

Comment: donde esta la imagen y como quieres enviar; ya que los archivos hay distintas formas de ser guardado...

Comment: forma 1: leer el archivo en formato binario y subirlo al sistema. convertirlo en blob o base64 y guardarlo en la base de datos.

Comment: forma 2: leer el archivo en formato binario y subirlo al sistema. colocarle un nombre especifico asignado por el sistema, guardar en la base de datos el path a el archivo ya en el disco del servidor.

Comment: formato 3: leer la url desde javascript y enviar la url al php para que la guarde en la base de datos. y utilizarla para cargar la imgen siempre que se requiera.

Comment: debes estar claro con lo que quieres y explicarlo detalladamente ...

Comment: @arcanisGK507 lo que quiero es tener la URL de la imagen en la BD y tambien mandarla por correo.... que en este caso seria la "VAR image"
que de los ejemplos que pones seria el formato 3..
cuando hago el console.url me la muestra pero no se como guardarla en una variable que la pueda leer php


la imagen se sube en automatico al director de archivos del host al cargarla o pegarla en el text area que se encuentra en el html, la sube en automatico

Comment: pues la verdad no se puede, por que tu HTML no tiene la etiqueta img ni la imagen con el src ... de donde se supone que debe leer ese dato el javascript???

Comment: si se supone que la imagen esta dentro de tu text summernote... estas complicando todo ... ya que no se en que lugar summernote esta subiendo la imagen ... si la imagen ya fue subida con summernot a tu servidor para que quieres volver a subirla por segunda vez???

Comment: si lo que intentas es subir tu imagen con summernote ... lo que estas haciendo no es correcto ... por si acaso te dejo este tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNzbPXZ5t_c

Comment: es que el problema no es subir la imagen el sumernote la sube en automatico al server... y como entra al directorio, genera una url, es la que quiero mandar para poder abrir la imagen desde el link....
el link o la (url) es precisamente la variable "VAR =image" esa es la quiero mandar a php. recalco el summernote ya guarda la imagen